# How to make changes to a joomla core module file

Tags: joomla

I am using this FREE module 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/os-responsive-image-gallery

What the client want, is to show the image names in lightbox view as well. Right now the image name is only being shown under the thumbnails, not with the image is in full preview, meaning in lightbox view.

I know I have to make the changes in the core files and I have opened them as well. But whatever changes I make in the js and uploaded it, it does not seem to show any response at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2 guesses, first cache issue and second is permission i think

Comment: cache issue maybe....regarding permission issue, I do not think that is a problem. Using FTP and making edits and saving it, it does not show any error.

Comment: so just try deleting cache of your browser or try another browser might help

Comment: are you sure you are editing correct files?

Comment: I am editing in the root folder -> modules -> mod-os-img-gallery and working in the fancy box js file